# set the cursor inside the function "keyboard.send_keys"

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, archlinux, autokey

I'm trying to set a shortcut in order to send an output like this: [DATE]_[thecaret/cursor].somethinelse

For example: *18-02-18_[myCursorHere].png*

This is the script for AutoKey under linux:

```
output = system.exec_command("date +'%Y%m%d'+'_$(cursor).png'")
keyboard.send_keys(output)
```

But the result is literally this one:

> 20180218+_$(cursor).png

Do you have any idea how to insert the cursor in the righ place using this script?

PS: Autokey also let me use the "phrase" function, where there are some macros, as "insert date" and "insert cursor" but I can't get it work. In that case the script is this one:

```
test <date format='%d-%m-%y'><cursor> something here
```

nothing happens (actually my text editor goes freeze)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution (using "time" instead of date command is better)

```
import time
t = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
length = "-.pdf"
keyboard.send_keys(t+length)
keyboard.send_key("<left>", len(length)-1)
```